# Confusion over field isomorphism F(a) onto F(b) where a and b are roots of an irreducible polynomial in F[t]?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

I am currently studying field extensions from Serge Lang's book *Undergraduate Algebra*. On page 269, he says this:

'Special case: Suppose that $\sigma$  is the identity on $F$ (any field), and let $\alpha,\beta$ be two roots of an irreducible polynomial in $F[t]$. Then there exists an isomorphism $\tau : F(a) \to F(b)$ which is the identity on $F$ and which maps $\alpha$ to $\beta$.'

So, I decided to test this theory out with the polynomial $t^4-5t^2+6$ whose roots are $\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3}$. So, by Lang's words there must be an isomorphism $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ onto $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})$ which is the identity on $F$ and maps $\alpha$ to $\beta$, so therefore $a+b\sqrt{2}$ must be mapped onto $a+b\sqrt{3}$ by this mapping. However, even though this mapping satisfies $\tau(v+w)=\tau(v)+\tau(w)$ where $v,w$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$, it does not satisfy $\tau(vw)=\tau(v)\tau(w)$ as $(ac+2bd)+(ad+bc)\sqrt3$ does not equal $(ac+3bd)+(ad+bc)\sqrt3$ - note the difference between $2bd$ and $3bd$. So, this mapping $\tau$ is clearly not an isomorphism. Where have I gone wrong with this, have I missed out a step or a hidden subtlety?

Comment: But its not irreducible so the result does not apply $\ (t^2-2)(t^2-3)\ \ $

Comment: $t^4-5t+6=(t^2-2)(t^2-3)$

Comment: I've applied LaTeX formatting to part of your question, so you can see how it's done. To get greek letters, you type `\tau` or `\beta`; I didn't apply these changes because I wanted to mostly preserve what you wrote.

Comment: Oh god sorry. I thought accidentally for a second that irreducible just meant that the roots were not in Q because I was only considering linear factors. Oh well my mistake sorry

Comment: How do I close the question now?

Comment: You simply accept @mercio's answer. You might go ahead and edit the original question to practice using LaTeX, though. :)

Comment: Yh sure thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$t^4-5t^2+6 = (t^2-3)(t^2-2)$ is reducible, and the theorem needs an irreducible polynomial.